# Is there a best practice way to hide component using react router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

To hide the navbar on the home component I am doing the following

```
const NavbarComponent = (props) => {
    console.log(props);

    if (props.match.path === '/') {
        return null;
    } else
        return (
```

it works fine, I need to have access to the router so I can send people to locations dependant on the props object , is there a better way to do it such that I have all router logic in the same place?

this is the current state of my router

```
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Route component={Navbar} />

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

                    <Route exact path="/api/:city/electronics" component={Electronics} />
                    <Route exact path="/api/:city/labour" component={Labour} />

                    <Route exact path="/api/posts/item/:id" component={ItemDetails} />

                    <Route exact path="/create/:city/:category" component={CreatePost} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
```

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why your `NavBar` component is in it's own `Route`. Any components contained within the Router have access to the entire Router api, including `Link` - they do not need to be a Route to do so.

I would suggest wrapping all the Routes that include the `NavBar` with that component. The Routes will then be displayed as children of the Navbar component.

Here is a simplified example:

```
// App.js
return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <NavBar>
            <Route exact path="/electronics" component={Electronics} />
            <Route exact path="/labour" component={Labour} />
          </NavBar>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );

//NavBar.js
return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link to="/electronics">Electronics</Link>
        <Link to="/labour">Labour</Link>
      </div>
      <div>{props.children}</div>
    </>
  );
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-microservice-gzxd0)

Comment: what is the props.children referring to?

Comment: The components that you wrap `NavBar` with.

Comment: sorry, im confused about that, usually I use the react-router to route based on what routes I send, I dont usually use the Link , so {props.children} is just to explan to me, "whatever you want to link those routes we just wrapped in the navbar place them here" , is that right?

Comment: @jcx3x the wrapped `Route`s from the router in App.js, but they can be any wrapped components.

Comment: Any active JSX you put between the NavBar tags will be rendered as `props.children` by the NavBar component as its literally a child of that component. You could put a `<p>` tag in there and that would also be rendered. It doesn't really matter whether you are using Link or Redirect, or pushing paths to the history object, Router will respond the same way. When a route becomes active because it's path matches the url, it will be rendered via `props.children`.

Comment: cool. Also I get a bug where the createPost will not show if it is in the same area as navbar, I had this also when I had them both  inside the switch, only when I remove navbar from the switch then they both show, could it be an issue with the :wildcard routes?

Comment: I couldn't say unfortunately, you should make a new post if it remains an issue.

Comment: I dont return the create post component in the navbar's return, but I just use that for react-router to know, "hey i want navbar to be present with these two routes" ,  is that expected behaviour, or should I be returning in navbar, if its wrapped around these two

Comment: In a sense, but react-router doesn't really 'know' anything - all it actually does is toggle 'active/inactive' on certain components when the path matches. You're telling the NavBar component that it should dynamically render any children that it may or may not have in the div provided. That div, by the way, is basically going to be a container for the rest of your site content. If you're struggling to visualise it, I would recommend getting/opening React Dev Tools and looking at the component tree for this code.